# upload image from pc and don't show jsp file

Tags: html, file, jsp, file-upload, show

T want to upload image from my pc and show jsp file but can't. When upload image and after show this image in jsp file image's url is missing. Only show in jsp file this image's path Example: name.jpg.
I need all path address .Example : C://dell//....//k.jpg
How I solved it?
HTml code is here:

```
<form  action="x" method="get">

 Urun kategori:<input type="file"  name="urunresim"/><p></p>
 <input type="submit" value="urunekle"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And Example :result is name.jpg but I need all path address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the path to the file on the visitor's computer wouldn't be helpful for most situations on the WWW and browsers do not make it possible.

You need to actually upload the file.

- Use `method="post"`
- Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Then you'll have access to the uploaded file in your Java and can save it in a location on your webserver that you can work out the URL for.

Comment: I did your said but result write null ?

Comment: Make sure you are using [the right functions to read the uploaded file](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm).

Comment: @Quention <html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="x" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="urunresim" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html> write it but result is null.Do I need to add someting code in my servlet?